# Why do these images load so slowly in Opera?

Tags: image, webserver, opera, page-load-time

In FireFox and IE, the images on [this page](http://www.triangelos.no/members) load almost instantly (especially when they're cached by the browser).

But in Opera they load super slow. Even had to select one of them to "reload" to get it to appear. Can anyone see why this would be? Is it a problem with the webpage or how the images are served, or is it a problem with Opera settings? Been looking for image cache settings, but haven't really found anything that looks abnormal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here they load about as slowly in Chrome, but the animation seems to appear somewhat slower in Opera. I think the reason they load slowly is that all images redirect somewhere else - for example http://www.triangelos.no/u/10/thumb redirecting to http://www.triangelos.no/uploads/2012/05/4fc4028947b4b_875e059c43d1aaafab4db5afe569f10c.jpg_thumb.jpeg . Browsers are reluctant to cache redirects because they might redirect somewhere else next time, so you'll have to wait while each URL is re-checked before the actual images are loaded from cache.

Comment: Can I improve the redirect somehow so that the browsers are less reluctant to re-check?

Comment: It would be better to link directly to the real files without any redirect at all. Then all browsers should cache the files.

Comment: Obviously, but it doesn't only redirect. It also generates the actual file if it doesn't already exist, before it redirects.

Comment: I'd say that's perhaps not the best architecture..if the main page is generated dynamically I presume it can check if a thumbnail exists and link directly if it does?

Comment: Well, anythings possible of course. Thing is that these URLs are in user-written markdown posts stored in the database. So they can write for example `![u/5/small]`. So to swap that out with the actual URL I'd have to parse the html after parsing the markdown and go through it all. Maybe that's not a terrible solution, but just feels so much more tedious than this way :p

Comment: Doing the rewrite now and yes, that sure sped things up quite a bit!